# Laravel Relations with Resources -> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried looking high and low for a solution to this, but met with failure. So here goes:

I am making a photo gallery module for a website. I have one model called 'GalleryName' and another called 'GalleryPhoto' and established a hasMany relation between them.

I am using Vue JS and the package I used to display the photos demand that I use the word 'title' as key for the name of the photo and 'src' as key for the full path to the file I have in storage. Instead of changing my database and other logic, I decided to use a resource file to change the keys and values.

First of all, here are my migrations:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateGalleryNamesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('gallery_names', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('gallery_name');
            $table->string('gallery_cover_photo');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('gallery_names');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateGalleryPhotosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('gallery_photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('gallery_name_id');
            $table->string('photo_title');
            $table->string('photo_image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('gallery_photos');
    }
}
```

Here are my Models:

```
// Gallery Name
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GalleryName extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function gallery_photos(){
        return $this->hasMany(GalleryPhoto::class);
    }
}
```

```
// Gallery Photo
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GalleryPhoto extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function gallery_name(){
        return $this->belongsTo(GalleryName::class);
    }  
}
```

Here are my resource files:

```
// Gallery Name Resource
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class GalleryNameResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        // return parent::toArray($request);

        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'gallery_name' => $this->gallery_name,
            'gallery_cover_photo' => $this->gallery_cover_photo,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'gallery_photos' => GalleryPhotoResource::collection($this->gallery_photos)
        ];   

    }
}
```

I am using this line, 'gallery_photos' => GalleryPhotoResource::collection($this->gallery_photos), since that is what the documentation tells you to do when you need to use resource inside a relationship.

```
// Gallery Photo Resource
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class GalleryPhotoResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        // return parent::toArray($request);

        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'gallery_name_id' => $this->gallery_name_id,
            'title' => $this->photo_title,
            'src' => '/storage/photo_gallery_images/'.$this->photo_image,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,            
        ];       
    }
}
```

I am using this line, 'src' => '/storage/photo_gallery_images/'.$this->photo_image, since I stored the filename only in database and now I need the full qualified path and not just the  filename as per my package requirements.

I declared a show method in my controller like this:

```
// Gallery Name Controller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\GalleryName;
use App\Http\Resources\GalleryNameResource;

class GalleryNameController extends Controller
{

public function show($id)
{
        $gallery_name = new GalleryNameResource(GalleryName::where('id', $id)->select('id', 'gallery_name','gallery_cover_photo' , 'created_at')->with(['gallery_photos' => function($query) {
            return $query->select(['id', 'gallery_name_id', 'photo_title', 'photo_image', 'created_at']);
        }])->first());

        if($gallery_name){
            return response()->json($gallery_name, 200);
        }

        return response()->json('Gallery Not Found !!', 404);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is using a relationship, but also the Resource files I declared earlier.

Now when I am using Postman and when I provide an id that exists(as a route parameter), it shows ther right JSON response. e.g

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "gallery_name": "Some Gallery 1",
    "gallery_cover_photo": "pexels-lena-goncharova-8692688-400x300_1628567178.jpg",
    "created_at": "2021-08-10T03:46:18.000000Z",
    "gallery_photos": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "gallery_name_id": 1,
            "title": "Photo 1",
            "src": "/storage/photo_gallery_images/pexels-lena-goncharova-8692688-900x800_1628567237.jpg",
            "created_at": "2021-08-10T03:47:17.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "gallery_name_id": 1,
            "title": "Photo 2",
            "src": "/storage/photo_gallery_images/pexels-lena-goncharova-8692688-400x300_1628567251.jpg",
            "created_at": "2021-08-10T03:47:31.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I provide an id that is non-existant in database, it gives me an 'Trying to get property 'id' of non-object' error. I found a work-around but in a hacky fashion. Regardless, I wish to know the nature of this error or why this is happening since I can't find what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GalleryNameResource` is the problem here.

Let's reformat your code so it's easier to read:

```php
public function show($id)
{

        $gallery_instance = GalleryName::where('id', $id)->select('id', 'gallery_name','gallery_cover_photo' , 'created_at')->with(['gallery_photos' => function($query) {
            return $query->select(['id', 'gallery_name_id', 'photo_title', 'photo_image', 'created_at']);
        }])->first();

        // $gallery_name == null if id doesn't exist
        
        $gallery_name = new GalleryNameResource($gallery_instance);

        // again, if the id doesn't exist, you are passing null to the resource, 
        // it's like writing new GalleryNameResource(null);

        // Remember: $gallery_name, in your code, IS NOT a GalleryName instance. 
        // It is a GalleryNameResource instance. 
        // It'll never be null or false, so the next condition is always true.

        if($gallery_name){
            return response()->json($gallery_name, 200);
        }

        return response()->json('Gallery Not Found !!', 404);
    }
}
```

When you send your `GalleryNameResource` to the response, Laravel will convert it to JSON.

This is why you get the error:

```php
public function toArray($request)
    {
        // return parent::toArray($request);

        return [
            'id' => $this->id,

            // 'id' => $this->id, is very likely your error

           // Laravel will try to get the id of... null
           // $this->id translates to $this->resource->id
           // so it translates to $this->null->id

           // Trying to get property id.... Error.

            'gallery_name' => $this->gallery_name,
            'gallery_cover_photo' => $this->gallery_cover_photo,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'gallery_photos' => GalleryPhotoResource::collection($this->gallery_photos)


        ];   

    }
```

How to fix your problem?

```php
public function show($id)
{
        $gallery_name = GalleryName::where('id', $id)->select('id', 'gallery_name','gallery_cover_photo' , 'created_at')->with(['gallery_photos' => function($query) {
            return $query->select(['id', 'gallery_name_id', 'photo_title', 'photo_image', 'created_at']);
        }])->first();

        if(!$gallery_name){
           return response()->json('Gallery Not Found !!', 404);
        }

        return response()->json(new GalleryNameResource($gallery_name), 200);
    }
}
```

A cleaner way of solving this would be to use implicit route bindings, check this in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: Wow. Done and dusted. Thanks a lot man. Appreciate the time and effort you spent to help out a little guy. I suppose I need to learn more about resources and all.